# Redirect after form Submit (CSR)

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Within a SharePoint form overriden by CSR (Client Side Rendering).

I tried adding a new button which does pretty much the same as the Save button except that it redirects to another form with given parameters.

The thing is, the redirection does not work.
I tried redirecting by changing the "action" property of the form but it doesn't seem to be taken in count.

Here is the new button :
`<input id="custom_addLine" type="button" name="custom_addLine" value="+" class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth">`

Here is the function called by the button and the addLine method following :

```
$('#custom_addLine').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    addLine(getQueryStringParameter('ID'));
});


function addLine(id) {
    if(!PreSaveItem()) {
        return false;
    }
    var actionUrl = "/Lists/PurchaseRequestLine/NewForm.aspx?PurchaseRequestID="+ id;
    var encodedActionUrl = encodeURIComponent(actionUrl);

    var newFormAction = location.pathname + '?Source=' + encodedActionUrl;
    $('#aspnetForm').attr('action',newFormAction);

    if(SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ1')){
        return false;
    }
    WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions('custom_addLine', "", true, "", "", false, true));
}
```

getQueryStringParameter is a custom made function to retrieve parameters from URI (which works).

The tricky part is that I want to preserve the default action URI in case the original Save button is clicked on, which is why action parameter is modified on the fly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the `Source` attribute directly from the original action:

```
 function addLine(id) {
    if(!PreSaveItem()) {
        return false;
    }

    var oldActionUrl = $('#aspnetForm').attr('action');
    var oldSource = GetUrlKeyValue("Source", true, oldActionUrl);

    var newSource = "/Lists/PurchaseRequestLine/NewForm.aspx?PurchaseRequestID="+ id;

    var newActionUrl = oldActionUrl.replace(oldSource, encodeURIComponent(newSource));

    WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions('custom_addLine', "", true, "", newActionUrl, false, true));
}
```

Comment: Will this still submit the form to the same location ? I mean originally SharePoint redirects after the submit using the "Source" parameter given in the URI is there any way to redirect elsewhere than where the Source parameter is pointed at ?

Comment: Does the original Source parameter is stored In the original form action? When you restore the original action, the next submit will result to the same (depending of input values)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the problem. Does changing the form action works ? If not, my reponse can help you, otherwise is it your Source attribute that does'nt work ?

Comment: It's more about changing the Source parameter than the Action attribute. I want the form to keep submitting like it used to but to redirect to another source. The thing is, I don't know how SharePoint native forms manage the Source parameter, if it's simply taken from URI or stored elsewhere (I could modify).

Comment: Original save button had to be overriden in order the redirection to occur. I modified your answer consequencely.

Answer (score 2):

Please **remove event.preventDefault();** from your code, it is responsible for redirection does not work

```
$('#custom_addLine').click(function(event){    
addLine(getQueryStringParameter('ID'));
});
```